# Update array using dispatch and avoid infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am using JSX to build a function that reads user's profile and updates it when click is performed. The `userProfiles` should contain user profiles and has some initial user profile, it should be updated with its existing contents and whatever is in `newProfile` when button `submit` is clicked. I used `useState` to perform the action but somehow it still goes into an infinite loop. Maybe `useMemo` could solve the problem?

The `setProfile` is the back-end function that writes the data into the DB (can be igonred in this case).

My code is as below:

```
export const AddProfile = () => {
    let userProfiles = [{mail: "firstguy@something.com", display: "someguy"}];
    const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState([])
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let newProfile = userProfiles
        setProfile(newProfile)
    },[profile])

    
    const onClickAdd = () => {

        let newProfile = [
            {mail: "zsdfsdfsdf.zheng@ericsson.com", display:"Börje"},
            {mail: "basdb.zheng@ericsson.com", display:"Olle"},
            {mail: "123132.zheng@ericsson.com", display:"kent"}
        ]

        dispatch(setProfile(newProfile))
        }
}
return (
   <button onclick={onClickAdd()}>submit</button>
)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have a typo, `onclick={onClickAdd()}` should be `onclick={onClickAdd}`, the rest of your code looks fine

Comment: Beside that, `dispatch(setProfile(newProfile))` doesn't make sense because `setProfile` doesn't return anything and, when you call `setProfile` you'll trigger the `useEffect(() => {..}, [profile])` which doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onClick method like this:

```
<button onClick={onClickAdd}>submit</button>
```

or, if you want to pass any parameters to it, use it like this:

```
<button onClick={() => onClickAdd()}>submit</button>
```